# What is difference between array and arrayOf ,hashmap and hashmapOf?

Tags: kotlin

What is a difference among different way of collections declaration?

I want to know the difference between:

- `array` and `arrayOf`
- `hashmap` and `hashmapOf`

[image]

Comment: Please explain your question further.

Comment: imean what relationship between array and arrayof ,hashmap and hashmap of

Comment: thanks you very much .i mean what purpose use it .are anthor way to write Arraylist and array

Comment: This is not a duplicate: as I understand it, the OP is asking, "why do we have both Array and ArrayOf"? The linked "duplicate" is explaining differences between Array, List, MutableList, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`Array` and `Hashmap` are constructors of the classes `Array` and `Hashmap`.

```
Array(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
HashMap(initialCapacity: Int, loadFactor: Float = 0.0f)
HashMap(initialCapacity: Int)
```

They are used to make a collection with specific size setting. You will NOT need them in usual situations.

```
// same as val arr = arrayOf(0, 2, 4, 8)
val arr = Array(4, index -> index * 2)

// map with initial capacity 8, which means that the map will prepare memory for 8 elements at the beginning.
val map = HashMap(8)
```

---

`arrayOf` and `mapOf` are functions that returns a new collection which has elements same as the parameters

```
inline fun <reified T> arrayOf(vararg elements: T): Array<T> (source)
fun <K, V> hashMapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>): HashMap<K, V> (source)

val arr1 = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val arr2 = arrayOf("D", "E", "FG", "H")
val map1 = mapOf("a" to 2, "b" to 3)
val map2 = mapOf(4 to "SDF", 7 to "E", 8 to "T")
```

Comment: I would add that `listOf` and `mapOf` return *some implementation* of `List` and `Map` respectively

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin collections have three types `List`, `Set` and `Map`. These collections are mutable and immutable. Maps are Hashmap which is key-value pairs.

The following are definitions from Kotlin documentation:

**List:**

> A generic ordered collection of elements. Methods in this interface
>   support only read-only access to the list; read/write access are
>   supported through the MutableList interface.

```
val numbers: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
```

**Set:**

> A generic unordered collection of elements that does not support
>   duplicate elements. Methods in this interface support only read-only
>   access to the set; read/write access is supported through the
>   MutableSet interface.

```
val animals = mutableSetOf("Lion", "Dog", "Cat")
```

**Map:**

> A collection that holds pairs of objects (keys and values) and
>   supports efficiently retrieving the value corresponding to each key.
>   Map keys are unique; the map holds only one value for each key.
>   Methods in this interface support only read-only access to the map;
>   read-write access is supported through the MutableMap interface.

```
val populations = mutableMapOf(
        Pair("Toronto", 3000),
        Pair("Windsor", 400)
)
```

Now the difference between `mutableListOf`, `mutableSetOf` and `mutableMapOf`, and `listOf`, `setOf` and `mapOf` is changeability. You can add value(s) to collections which have `mutable` keyword in front and you cannot add values(s) to collections which do not have `mutable` keyword in front.

The following are examples of immutable collections:

```
var nums = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

var names = setOf("Bob", "John", "Elizabeth")

var population = mapOf(
        Pair("Windsor", 2000),
        Pair("Toronto", 50000)
)
```

**HashMap:**

HashMap is a Kotlin class of collection based on MutableMap interface. It stores the data in the form of key-value pairs.

```
val hashMap:HashMap<Int,String> = HashMap<Int,String>()
```

The **Array**

> represents an array (specifically, a Java array when targeting the JVM
>   platform)
>   * Array instances can be created using the [arrayOf], [arrayOfNulls] and [emptyArray]

.

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org